# Rhino Mock Expect() method triggers call on expected function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am using Rhino Mocks 3.6 in C# and i am experiencing problems when mocking objects instead of interfaces.
Could somebody please explain why methods are actually called when just defining an expectation?

```
   public class MockingBird
   {
      public void TestMethod()
      {
         throw new Exception("Method call!");
      }
   }
```

...

```
 [TestMethod]
  public void TestMock()
  {
     var mockedMockingBird = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<MockingBird>();
     mockedMockingBird.Expect(x => x.TestMethod());
  }
```

Comment: Your method isn't virtual - I would expect that to cause Rhino Mocks problems. Note that even the author of Rhino Mocks doesn't use it now - you should at least consider using an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mock methods that are **not overridable**. When creating mock instance Rhino does the following:

1. It generates dynamic assembly in runtime (using [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) library to do that)
2. In that assembly Rhino creates a new type, deriving from the type you want to mock
3. Members of that new type are overridden to insert recording/stubbing logic

In practice, you can only mock `virtual`/`abstract` methods of classes and any member of interface.

Keep in mind that this limitation is present in all free mocking frameworks.

Comment: I smashed my hand against my head. Of course, that´s it!